# JPA-Hibernate connecting to DB2 db with JBoss AS 7: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, persistence

JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final-redhat-1

Close to having data returned in objects... but so far, no dice.  I can connect.  I can execute queries.  I can get the Entity Manager OK.  But I am getting this error:

```
[org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter] (default task-1) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT c FROM com.bank.ro.Collateral c where c.Id = 992469
```

I have the following project structure; I am using IntelliJ:

```
root
  - pricingAPI
   - main
     - java
      - com
       - bank
        - ro
          Collateral.java
        - dao
          JPAUtility.java
          JPQLDataAccessor.java
        - resource
          PricingSvcResource.java
    - resources
      persistence.xml
    - webapp
     - META-INF
       persistence.xml
     - WEB-INF
       beans.xml
       web.xml

   - pricingEAR
    - src
     - main
       hibernate.cfg.xml
      - application
       - META-INF
         persistence.xml
         application.xml
```

The files:

Collateral.java:

```
package com.bank.ro;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@ManagedBean(value = "collateral")
@Table(name = "schema.collateral")
//@Entity(name="com.bank.ro.Collateral")
public class Collateral {
 private long id;
 private int version;
 private Timestamp createDate;
 ...
 public Collateral(){}

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
 public long getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 @Basic
 @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
 public int getVersion() {
    return version;
 }

 public void setVersion(int version) {
     this.version = version;
 }
 ...
}
```

JPAUtility.java:

```
package com.bank.dao;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@ManagedBean(value = "JPAUtility")
@PersistenceContext(unitName="collateral-persistence-unit", name="collateral-persistence-unit")
public class JPAUtility {
 private static final EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
 static {
    emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("collateral-persistence-unit");
 }
 private static EntityManager entityManager = null;

 public JPAUtility(){};

 public static void setEntityManager(){
    entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
 }
 public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if(entityManager == null) {
        setEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
 }
 public static void close(){
    emFactory.close();
 }
}
```

JPQLDataAccessor.java:

```
package com.bank.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.bank.ro.Collateral;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

public class JPQLDataAccessor
{
    public static List<Collateral> retrieveCollateralRecords(EntityManager em, Long id)
    {
        final StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String qry = "SELECT c FROM " + Collateral.class.getName() + " c where c.Id = " + id.longValue();
        queryStringBuilder.append(qry);
        List colls = em.createQuery(qry).getResultList();
        return colls;
    }
}
```

PricingSvcResource.java:

```
package com.bank.pricing.resource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.bank.dao.JPAUtility;
import com.bank.dao.JPQLDataAccessor;
import com.bank.ro.Collateral;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.bank.ro.Application;
import com.bank.ro.OffersRequest;
import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.InjectService;

@Path("/") // hello-world
@DenyAll
@Api(value = "/", tags = "PricingSvcResource Operation") 
public class PricingSvcResource {


@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
@Path("hello-world/")
@PermitAll
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Hello world text.")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class)})
public Response getHelloWorld()
{
 return Response.ok("Hello world").build();
}

@GET
@PermitAll
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Collateral details by Collateral ID")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class)})
@Path("details/{collateral_id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public Response getCollateralDetails(@PathParam("collateral_id") String collateralId) {

    if(collateralId==null || collateralId.isEmpty() || !collateralId.matches("^\\d+$")) {
        return Response.ok("There was no collateralId or it was an unusable value.")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    }
    EntityManager em = JPAUtility.getEntityManager();

    List<Collateral> collList = JPQLDataAccessor.retrieveCollateralRecords(em, Long.parseLong(collateralId));
    Collateral coll = null;
    if( collList.size() > 0 )
    {
        coll = collList.get(0);
    }
    if(coll != null) {
        return Response.ok(coll.getDescription()).build();
    }
    return Response.ok("No collateral found for that ID").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
 }
}
```

persistence.xml (all such files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="collateral-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/collateral-ds</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.bank.ro.Collateral</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="persistence-units/collateral-persistence-unit"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:db2://{host}:{port}/{DB}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
        <property name="wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap" value="false" />
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     version="3.0">
 <display-name>pricing-svc</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Health APIs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/health</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/health/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Hello World APIs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello-world</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public APIs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/public</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Secured APIs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>A_ROLE</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
 <display-name>pricing-svcEAR</display-name>
 <module id="Module_1404334226710">
    <web>
        <web-uri>pricing-svc.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>v1/collateral2</context-root>
    </web>
 </module>
 <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
         <session-factory>
              <property name="show_sql">true</property>
              <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
              <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
              <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">SessionFactory</property>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2://{host}:{port}/{schema}</property>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXX</property>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXX</property>
              <mapping class="com.bank.ro.Collateral"/>
         </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Finally, my standalone.xml, at least the datasource part:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/collateral-ds"
                        pool-name="collateral-ds"
                        enabled="true"
                        use-java-context="true"
                        jta="true">
                <datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource</datasource-class>
                <connection-url>${env.DS_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
                <connection-property name="driverType">
                    4
                </connection-property>
                <connection-property name="serverName">
                    ${env.DS_CONNECTION_SERVER_NAME}
                </connection-property>
                <connection-property name="portNumber">
                    ${env.DS_CONNECTION_PORT}
                </connection-property>
                <connection-property name="databaseName">
                    ${env.DS_CONNECTION_DATABASE_NAME}
                </connection-property>
                <connection-property name="currentSchema">
                    ${env.DS_CONNECTION_CURRENT_SCHEMA}
                </connection-property>
                <driver>${env.DS_DRIVER}</driver>
                <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>${env.DS_POOL_MIN_SIZE}</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>${env.DS_POOL_MAX_SIZE}</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>${env.DS_USER_NAME}</user-name>
                    <password>${env.DS_PASSWORD}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2StaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>


            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.ibm.db2.jcc" module="com.ibm.db2.jcc">
                    <datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource</datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="xxx-db2-driver" module="com.xxx.inf.jdbc.30">
                    <driver-class>com.xxx.inf.jdbc3.drivers.Db2ThrottledJdbcDriver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
....
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <concurrent>
            <context-services>
                <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
            </context-services>
            <managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
            </managed-thread-factories>
            <managed-executor-services>
                <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
            </managed-executor-services>
            <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
            </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        </concurrent>
        <default-bindings
                context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default"
                managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
                managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default"
                managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"
                datasource="java:jboss/datasources/collateral-ds"
        />

    </subsystem>
```

I think that's everything germane, though as we all know... things can be germane without announcing themselves.

If anyone has any idea, let me know.  Some more chatter leading up to the error:

```
12:26:03,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
12:26:03,718 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
12:26:03,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started in 14587ms - Started 410 of 476 services (116 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
12:27:00,639 INFO  [com.xxx.inf.api.auth.mechanisms.RestAuthenticationMechanism] (default task-1) Non protected resource, ID-Claim not checked
12:27:00,743 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) SELECT c FROM com.bank.ro.Collateral c where c.Id = 992469
12:27:00,758 WARN  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter] (default task-1) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT c FROM com.bank.ro.Collateral c where c.Id = 992469
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Fix is to .jar up the persister class and place it in *EAR_file*/lib folder.  Then redeploy the .ear.

This is bad.  This means I have to make .jarring up the persister class(es) and copy them into *EAR_file*\lib before .earring up the .war, etc. a regular thing, esp. if my persister classes change, though they probably won't too much.

Possibly this is also necessary for the more dynamic business classes but maybe not since I think this is a Hibernate-scoped issue (well, I hope so).  In my case I will have to update the build script to do this for me each time I run build.

There was a reason why Spring was invented. :)

Thanks to all who read my problem.